# Reshape a row to columns based in condition data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have this data frame in R:

```
               x
1   simon.jones@studio24.net
2   beth.parkin@mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk
3   43
4   simon.jones@studio24.net
5   isaac.lowe@studio24.net
6   13
7   simon.jones@studio24.net
8   samp466@gmail.com
9   31
10  simon.jones@studio24.net
11  suli447@googlemail.com
12  32
```

I would like to have a data frame with 3 columns, not just one:

```
                x                          y                  value
1   simon.jones@studio24.net  beth.parkin@mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk    43
.
.
.
```

How can I reshape my data frame for infinite rows to get the 3 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), ncol=3, byrow = T))
                        V1                            V2 V3
1 simon.jones@studio24.net beth.parkin@mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk 43
2 simon.jones@studio24.net       isaac.lowe@studio24.net 13
3 simon.jones@studio24.net             samp466@gmail.com 31
4 simon.jones@studio24.net        suli447@googlemail.com 32
```

Comment: The only downside is that `value` should probably be numeric in the end.